# XSLTransform is taking too much time in rendering HTML

Tags: php, html, xml, performance, debugging

I have a file in admin panel **locationlist.php** which is taking too much time in loading i debug that and what i found is that there is a transform function which is making all the mess. And at the end of this file I'm transforming the **XML to HTML** as below:

```
    $strPageHTML = XSLTransform( $strXML, APPL_XSL_DIR.'locationlist.xsl', $strError );
    echo $strPageHTML;
```

Now the problem is that it is taking **25-35** seconds in transforming the $strXML to HTML. Is there any better way to optimize the speed or lower the loading time?

Thanks

Comment: First, have you optimize Xpath in your xlst file ? and your treatment (no many loops templates, calcul ...)

Comment: Which XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: @GabrielGourrat how to optimze Xpath?

Comment: - Avoiding "//element", prefering "/root/element"
- Avoiding many Xpath in one expression concat(substring(/root/element,0,1),"_",substring(/root/element,1,1)) prefering   /root/element/text()/substring(.,0,2)
- etc... look google "optimize xpath"

Comment: "<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"; version="1.0">" it's not the processor. Processor is what will interpret your xsl and do the conversion to xml/html (like Raptor, Saxon, XsltProcessor ...)

Comment: It is XsltProcessor @DMC19

Comment: @Iftikharuddin have you tried with other processor? How many lines have your XSLT? As Gabriel said, try to improve your XSLT.

Comment: No i didn't tried but client is forcing to work in this one. @DMC19